# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is local ring iff $n$ is a power of a prime number

Tags: ring-theory

$\mathbb{Z}_n$ is integers modulo $n$. Local ring is a commutative ring if it has a unique maximal ideal. Please help me prove the claim.

Comment: I don't understand why would anyone want to close this question. Please give a reason!

Comment: what do you call $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ to? The integers modulo $\;n\;$? The $\;n$-adics...? The close vote is too harsh imo, but it probably comes from the fact you show no self effort in your our question's solution.

Comment: integers modulo n, sorry for not explaining this earlier.

Comment: @math the reason is because you don't show effort, primarily.  (not my vote)

Comment: What relationship do the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and of $\mathbb{Z}$ have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two distinct primes $p$ and $q$ divide $n$, then
$$
n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq p\mathbb{Z}
$$
and
$$
n\mathbb{Z}\subseteq q\mathbb{Z}
$$
so $p\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are distinct maximal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Why are they distinct? (Hint: consider the quotient ring.)

The converse is easy: the only maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ a prime, $k>0$) is $p\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

You probably know (and if you don't prove it: it is a nice exercise) that a unitary commutative ring $\;R\;$ is a local one iff the set of all *non units* in the ring is an ideal, and in this case exactly this very ideal is the unique maximal one there is.

Well, show this is the case in $\;\Bbb Z_n:=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\;$ iff $\;n\;$ is a prime power.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem): it tells you that
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z}{n\Bbb Z}\simeq
\frac{\Bbb Z}{p_1^{e_1}\Bbb Z}\times\cdots\frac{\Bbb Z}{p_k^{e_k}\Bbb Z}
$$
if $n=\prod_{i=1}^kp_i^{e_i}$ is the primary decomposition of $n$. Now, what are the maximal ideals in a product of rings?